# Display 100 Points in 1 second : Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have a project where I am trying to update chart. in which 100 points to be displayed in each second.

For that I am trying [this example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) from the Highcharts.

But the chart stops responding to such event.

The code:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/vbkf7ed9/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 10);
            }
        }
    },

    time: {
        useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Random data',
        data: (function () {
            // generate an array of random data
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: Math.random()
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
```

Comment: seems you can't add data that fast ... even 2 per second (500ms interval) causes issues - 750ms is about the lowest stable value for the interval

Comment: is there any other charting library that can process data this fast ? @JaromandaX

Comment: don't know - perhaps removing the "animation" in highcharts could help

Comment: even with `animation: false` you'll be lucky to get 4 per second

Comment: made the animation to false. but the lines not covering the whole chart. u can check it in fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/vbkf7ed9/4/ @JaromandaX

Comment: I already tested it myself :p 4 per second is the maximum

Comment: so nothing can be done with this charting library @JaromandaX

Comment: Increasing number of visible points helps: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cpqj6ar8/ Simply removing initial points that have different range also helps: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cpqj6ar8/1/ One way or another, it's a bad idea to add a point every 10ms. You give browser less than 5ms to calculate the frame (assuming that browsers needs 5ms to render the frame). Instead I suggest to gather n-points and use `series.setData()`, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cpqj6ar8/3/ - it's displaying exactly 100points per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `redraw` parameter in `addPoint` method to false and call `chart.redraw()` at longer intervals:

```
chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
        load: function() {
            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0],
                chart = this;

            setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.random();
                series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
            }, 10);

            setInterval(function() {
                chart.redraw();
            }, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s3gh6q5j/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw

Comment: In the Fiddle the chart is not looking that nice as it supposed to be.
I may need the data to plot like the following example : https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/yq3Lp0hz/7/

Comment: I Know its a different charting library. but can this be functionality be done on the Highcharts also ?

Comment: Hi @debRoo, You need to disable `shift` parameter: https://jsfiddle.net/8kefjyoc/

Comment: two things. (1.) Te points get compressed and not shifting when reach some point

(2.) How many data points does it showing in 1 second time ?

Comment: Hi @debRoo, 1. You can fill the start data by nulls and use `shift` parameter. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tasf2j0z/ 2. 100 points per second.

Comment: I am very close to what I am want to achieve. If u can see the fiddle which I modified with the help of your fiddle. I just want 130 points to plot in One second. right now its plotting more than that.  Please check my fiddle below: https://jsfiddle.net/abnitchauhan/w0pLa7rm/2/

Comment: I updated the fiddle for the 130 points in one second. is my code correct ?

Comment: Now you are adding 1000 points per second. In this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qet83da2/ the points are added approximately 130 points per second.

Comment: Oh I made the mistake in my fiddle. I was supposed to write 1000/130. But still. I got my solution now. many thanks to you

Comment: the  ```100``` we mentioned below the chart redraw is I think Adding some extra delay(minor). Can we make the chart much more accurate than this ? if i try removing the ```100``` value. the data speed gets slow

Comment: You can adjust the interval time to your needs. If you decrease its value, the chart will be redrawn less times.

Comment: its tottally doing the opposite. if I set chart redraw value to ```1``` it's taking more time. the performace and speed is quite good. now all what it needs is accuracy

Comment: debRoo - The number of added points is still the same. Redrawing chart in 1ms interval is not necessery, you can do that in `addPoint`: https://jsfiddle.net/q5xb2ohd/

Comment: if you can see the console, the plotting speed decreases.

Comment: The chart is redrawn more often but the same number of points is added.